# Show properties of elements of $\mathcal{H}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I have problems with my homework. First of all: $\mathcal{H}^2$ means the Sobolev space, right? Because in the script we are using a $W$ for Sobolev spaces and the $\mathcal{H}^2$ can't be found anywhere.
My actual problem is this question:

> Let $\Omega_{\beta} := B_1(0)_{||\cdot||_\infty}\setminus\left\{z = r\exp(i\phi) \in \mathbb{C}\mid  r > 0, 0 \leq \phi \leq \beta \right\}$, $0\leq\beta\leq 2\pi$ an open and bounded domain, $\Gamma_\beta = \{z \mid r > 0, \phi = \beta \} \cap \partial\Omega_{\beta}$ part of its boundary. Furthermore, let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $f_\alpha(r) = r^\alpha \sin(\alpha\phi)$.
>
> For what values of $\alpha$ is $f_\alpha(r) \in\mathcal{H}^2(\Omega_{\beta})$ for all $\beta$?

So, assuming I am right and $H$ describes the Sobolev space. Then it means that $f$ has to to have 2nd weak derivatives in $L^2$. So is that really all I have to do: Try to calculate the 2nd weak derivatives and see whether the are in $L^2$ or is there something more I have overseen so far?

Comment: We need some precisions: $f_{\alpha}$ seems to have two arguments, $r$ and $\phi$. Indeed, $H$ or $\mathcal H$ is the space of functions which have weak derivatives of second order which are square integrable. Note that if $\beta\leq \beta_2$ then $\Omega_{\beta_1}\subset\Omega_{\beta_2}$. Last question: will $\Gamma_{\beta}$ be useful in the next question(s)?

Comment: $H^p$ usually is shorthand for $W^{2,p}$, it means all weak $p$-derivatives are square integrable.

Comment: Ok thank you. It was just a bit confusing, because in the lecture we use the W-notation, where as in the homework that H showed up, without further explanation.